# clearcase command to verify code merge

Tags: clearcase

Is there any clearcase command that checks if elements under a particular branch have been merged to main branch? Also, can the same command be used to check if elements with a particular label in a branch have been merged to main branch?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In some cases, you can also use the 'cleartool findmerge' command with the flag, '-whynot' and search through the results for the string, "already merged".

If you are looking to see if the LATEST version (not any version) on '.../my_branch' for every element in /vobs/myvob has been merged to the /main branch, from a view with a config spec picking /main/LATEST, you can use the following to report on the merge status of files from my_branch:

> cleartool findmerge /vobs/myvob -all -whynot -fver .../my_branch/LATEST -print

For the "label on a branch" scenario you mentioned, you can run this:

> cleartool findmerge /vobs/myvob -all -whynot -fver .../my_branch/MY_LABEL -print

Answer (score 0):

An element, in ClearCase, references a file or a folder. It is composed of a tree of versions which represents its history.

You don't verify if an element has been merged (it may have been merged many times in its history). You can find the last version merged (and see if it is the most recent one for a givne branch)

That generally involve looking for version with a hyperlink type "Merge":

```
cleartool find . -version "hltype(Merge)" -nxname -exec 'cleartool desc $CLEARCASE_PN' -print
```

If you check the branch main, you would look for '`->`' Merge hyperlinks (links coming to the branch main, which means the version has been merged to `/main`)

```
cleartool find /views/myview/vob/myvob -follow -dir -branch 'brtype(main)' -version '(hltype(Merge, <-))' -print
```

See more at "[How files and directories are merged](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.dev.doc/topics/cc_dev/how_merge_file_dir.htm)".